# Compiling errors using clang for if conditions

Tags: c, compilation, cs50

So, I wrote down this code where the main goal is to retrieve JPEGs from a memory card.

This is what I wrote until now. However, when compiling, it gives me errors on the conditions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Check for only the presence of 1 input to run
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage of only 1 command line argument");
        return 1;
    }
    //Name of the file storage in "name"
    char *name = argv[1];
    //As we know is 512B, give that specific syze
    char block[512];
    //Open file
    FILE *original = fopen (name, "r");
    //check if it has anything in it
    if (original == NULL)
    {
        printf ("The file has nothing on it\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //Variables to work with
    FILE *copia;
    char jpeg[8];
    int count = 0;
    //while reading its content
    while (fread (block, 512, 1, original) == 1)
    {
        //condition for the beggining of the jpeg
        if (block[0] == 0xff && block[1] == 0xd8 && block[2]==0xff && (block[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            //Case of the first jpeg
            if (count == 0)
            {
                sprintf (jpeg, "%03i.jpg", count);
                copia = fopen (jpeg, "w");
                fwrite (block, 512, 1, copia);
                count = count + 1;
                fclose (copia);
            }
            //Case for over
            if (count > 0)
            {
                sprintf (jpeg, "%03i.jpeg", count);
                count = count +1;
                copia = fopen (jpeg, "w");
                fwrite (block, 512, 1, copia);
                fclose(copia);
            }
        }
        //close file
        fclose(original);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Compiler messages:

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    recover.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o recover
recover.c:32:22: error: result of comparison of constant 255 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
        if (block[0] == 0xff && block[1] == 0xd8 && block[2]==0xff && (block[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            ~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~


recover.c:32:42: error: result of comparison of constant 216 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
        if (block[0] == 0xff && block[1] == 0xd8 && block[2]==0xff && (block[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
                                ~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~



recover.c:32:61: error: result of comparison of constant 255 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
        if (block[0] == 0xff && block[1] == 0xd8 && block[2]==0xff && (block[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
                                                    ~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~
3 errors generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'recover' failed
make: *** [recover] Error 1
```

Can anyone shed some light on this subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three `-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare` warnings/errors are caused by the fact that, in the `block[0] == 0xff` comparison, the `0xff` is an **integer** (`int`) constant, with a value of `255` but `block[0]` is a (signed) `char`, which has a range of `-128` thru `127`. Thus, as the message states, the result of the comparison will *always* be false. And similarly for the `block[1] == 0xd8` test (`0xd8` is `216`, also out-of-range for a `char`).

There are two ways to address the issue. The first (*not recommended*) is to explicitly cast the constants to `char` values before the comparison, as in `if (block[0] == (char)0xff ...` and so forth.

But a far better way is to use the `unsigned char` type for your `block` array, so use:

```c
unsigned char block[512];
```

instead of:

```c
char block[512];
```

The second method more accurately represents the component data elements of a JPEG file; and it eliminates the warnings, because an `unsigned char` has a range of `0` thru `255`.

Comment: But why do the unsigned syntax solved it?  Does it increase the range of "char"?

Comment: As I pointed out in the answer (or tried to) the range *sizes* of `unsigned char` and `char`  are the same but the former starts at 0 (so it can include up to 255) whereas the later, being able to accommodate both *positive* and *negative* values, has an upper limit of only 'half size', or 127.

Comment: @Alezzpt If the error is *strongly* related to this answer, then you can ask about it in a comment and I shall *try* to help. If it's (in your view) a *different* issue, then you could ask a new question.